# Exporting RcppParallel::RVector vs std::vector

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

Consider the following serial example function:

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp20)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector example_fun(int n) {
  Rcpp::NumericVector result (n);
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    result[i] = something();
  }
  return result;
}
```

Parallelizing this loop with OpenMP requires the use of e.g. `std::vector` or `RcppParallel::RVector`, as Rcpp vectors are not thread-safe. The corresponding parallel `std::vector` version is

```
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp20)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<double> example_fun(int n) {
  std::vector<double> result (n);
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    result[i] = something();
  }
  return result;
}
```

and similarly with `RcppParallel::RVector<double> example_fun(int n)` for `RcppParallel::RVector`.

If I understand correctly, exporting an `Rcpp::NumericVector` makes the data available to R without copying it, as it is essentially R's native data type. What I would like to know, is how exporting a `std::vector` or an `RcppParallel::RVector` works internally? Is the vector copied? Is it moved? Does it require type conversions? And importantly, is one of the two options clearly more efficient than the other?

As a quick additional question, I would also like to know, if the Rcpp tread safety issue also applies to vectorized simd loops: `#pragma omp simd` or `#pragma omp parallel for simd`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be complicating things for yourself here.  It helps to step back, and you can also inspect what R does if/when you play, *e.g.* the memory profiling options are good!

In a nutshell, R uses `SEXP` types and these have 'native' integer and double vectors -- which you can access from R as `integer(3)` and `double(4)` to create and allocate, respectively, a three and four element vector.

Now, using `Rcpp::IntegerVector` and `Rcpp::NumericVector` does the absolutely to the bit equivalent step. It uses R's own allocator, and the resulting object is indistinguishable to R from one created in R.  (It's of course the same via the C API of R itself, Rcpp acceses it.)

On the other hand, C++ STL objects like `std::vector`, or contributed types like `RVector` use *memory allocated elsewhere* (which helps *e.g.* with `RcppParallel` as you note and keeps it thread-safe) so for each of these *we must copy into an R data structure*.  And that really is the gist of it.  Data that "already is like R's own" needs no copy. Everything else needs a copy.

(As a total aside there is no C++20 anywhere in your example. Not even C++11. What you wrote would have built ten+ years ago when C++98 (!!) was still the default. Life is much better now under current R and current compilers so I hardly ever set standards plugins as C++14 or C++17 are already the default if you are on current-enough systems.)

Comment: Thank you for the nice and quick answer. I use `// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp20)]]` because the actual code uses `std::set::contains` in some places. And that member function was just added in C++20.

Comment: Yep that is the way it goes with extras. I also love the filesystem and regexp additions in C++17.  All good!